# How to "stretch" a procedural half-sphere texture on X and/or Y axis

Tags: geometry, functions, computational-geometry

I've implemented an Objective-C function to display the "height" of a half-sphere, with "1.0" being "full-height" and "0.0" being "no-height"

The sphere currently has a few parameters:

- Center (x,y: real coordinates)
- Radius (r: real value)

These values are currently being drawn in a texture with an independent size, provided that the minimum coordinate is (0,0) and the maximum is (1,1), which could be represented by a mathematical function like `f(px, py)`, where `px` and `py` are the points where I want the height of the given half-sphere.

Now, I want to add two more parameters to the sphere, a "x-stretch" and a "y-stretch" (we can call them `xs` and `ys`), where I could deform the sphere in the X or Y axis.

The current function is like this (provided that the values of "x", "y" and "r" are known):

- $ d(px, py) = \sqrt{(x-px)^2 + (y+py)^2} $ as being the distance from the center to the given point
- $ f(px, py) = \sqrt{1 - \frac{d(px, py)}{r}} $ as being the value (from 0.0 to 1.0) of the half-sphere height.

Note that `f` is only calculated if `d` is smaller than the radius(`r`)

I want a way to add `xs` and `ys` in the above equations, but I don't really know how to get around that.

If it helps, here's the Objective-C function that "solves" the above problem:

```
- (CGFloat)sphereValueAtPoint:(NSPoint)point center:(NSPoint)sphereCenter radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    CGFloat dist;

    dist = sqrt(pow(point.x - sphereCenter.x,2) + pow(point.y - sphereCenter.y, 2));
    if (dist > radius)
        return(0.0);

    return(sqrt(1 - pow(dist/radius, 2)));
}
```

I've also got a faster, optimized function, but it is not as easy to understand.

EDIT: Note that when `xs` and `ys` are both equal to `1.0`, no scaling should be done. If either are GREATER than `1.0`, the texture is stretched and if they are between `1.0` and `0.0`, the texture is compressed. You can assume that `xs` and `ys` are always greater than `0.0`.

EDIT2: As requested, I'm adding some images for clarification. White is 1.0, Black is 0.0 and the gray is in between (check tooltips).

[image: Regular sphere (<code>xs</code> and <code>ys</code> equals to 1.0)]
[image: X-Stretched sphere (<code>xs</code> = 1.2)]
[image: Y-Compressed sphere (<code>ys</code> = 0.9)]
[image: XY-deformed sphere (<code>xs</code> = 1.2 and <code>ys</code> = 0.9)]

Comment: I'm finding it very hard to understand your question. Can you add some diagrams?

Comment: Thanks for trying. I've added some images. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, what you are doing is computing a *height field* describing a hemisphere. I would recommend using that phrase in the future, by the way; just calling it a "texture" conveys very little, and makes one think of mapping a textured pattern onto the surface of a sphere.

Your stated formula isn't quite correct, though the code is. Allow me denote the variable point as $(x,y)$ and the center of the hemisphere as $(c_x,c_y)$, as is more usual. The formula for the height of the hemisphere should be
$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{1 - \frac{d(x,y)^2}{r^2}} = \sqrt{1 - \frac{(x-c_x)^2}{r^2} - \frac{(y-c_y)^2}{r^2}}.$$
If you want to scale its size by $s_x$ and $s_y$, all you have to do is
$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{1 - \frac{(x-c_x)^2}{(s_xr)^2} - \frac{(y-c_y)^2}{(s_yr)^2}}.$$

For what it's worth, you're really modelling an ellipsoid with semi-principal axes of length $x_sr$, $y_sr$, and $1$. The implicit equation of an ellipsoid centered at the origin with semi-principal axes of length $a$, $b$, and $c$ is
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1.$$
Substitute $a$, $b$, $c$ with their desired values, replace $x$ and $y$ by $x-c_x$ and $y-c_y$ to translate the origin, and solve for $f(x,y) = z$, and you get the formula above.

Comment: It worked flawlessly. The only change I made is that I first calculate $k = 1 - \frac{(x - c_x)^2}{(s_xr)^2}-\frac{(y - c_y)^2}{(s_yr)^2}$. If that is negative, I return the height field `0.0`. If not, I go ahead and return $\sqrt{k}$. Thanks a lot!